# What type of snake is this?

Tags: species-identification

[image: snake:]
We came across this snake when were on a hike in a typical dense forest in the Philippines. . Been wondering if this snake is venomous or not.

Comment: Where did you see this?  There are many countries with many "dense forests".

Comment: Definitely venomous. It's a viper but you should tell the exact geographical location for correct identification.

Comment: My guess is that it is a juvenile temple pit viper (*Tropidolaemus subannulatus*).

Comment: It's in Asia. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Jay Asia is a huge continent with diverse ecosystems. Can you be more precise with the geographical location?

Comment: It's in the Philippines.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include all the necessary information?

Answer (score 1):

It is a green tree python (Morelia viridis)

Comment: I think that's accurate. A young one, perhaps 10 months old.

Comment: Green tree pythons are limited to Australia: https://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Morelia_viridis/

Comment: Please add some references to support your answer. I guess your answer is also incorrect. The snake looks very much like a viper. Can you add some explanation on why you think it is a green tree python?

Comment: Thank you. I would agree. This one is close to a viper.